# How to ResetRoleInheritance for all websites, list, libraries, listitems and documents programmatically?

Tags: permissions

I would like to make a site collection read only programmatically. I used the

> `Site.ReadOnly = true`

, but is not working. Now I would like to remove all the permissions on the root website of the site collection. After this I would like to give all authenticated user read permissions. As last I would like to ResetRoleInheritance for all websites, libraries, lists, items, documents etc. What is the best way to do that programmatically in c#?

Answer (score 1):

I build this.

```
private void ResetRoleInheritance(SPSite site)
        {
            foreach (SPWeb website in site.AllWebs)
            {
                // Reset role inheritance, except root website
                if (website.HasUniqueRoleAssignments && !website.Url.Equals(site.Url))
                {
                    website.Update(); // TODO is this needed
                    website.ResetRoleInheritance();
                }

                // reset role inheritance on all lists, libraries, items, documents
                foreach (SPList list in website.Lists)
                {
                    if (list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        list.ResetRoleInheritance();
                    }

                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                        {
                            item.ResetRoleInheritance();
                        }
                    }
                }

                website.Dispose();
            }
        }
```